# Importing file info in Angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6

The question is about how to run file explorer, select file from any directory and then get file information about chosen file to show it on web page. I can't find any useful tutorial which cover this questions.

Can anybody help?

Comment: did you try ng-file-upload library

Comment: I stand corrected by @NagaSaiA --> ng-file-upload library --> https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload